Ubuntu 24.04 - Surface Pro 5 keyboard cover touchpad stutters when not touched for a few seconds
Freshly installed 24.04 on my Surface Pro 5 after using 20.04 for awhile, and I'm having a problem I wasn't before. Basically, if I haven't used the cover in awhile (approx. 5 seconds), the trackpad will yield jittery input the first time I touch it next. I've installed the Linux Surface kernel, and this behavior occurs before and after installing it. I've also tried both Wayland and Xorg but that didn't affect it either. Given that typing prevents this from happening, I assume that this is the cover going to sleep and waking back up. Is there any known way to prevent it from sleeping or at least extend the time before it does? It wouldn't kill me to just downgrade back to 20.04 if it continues but I'd prefer to stick with the newer version if possible.

Are you sure the kernel is good for Ubuntu 24.04?

I assume so. Everything else (screen touch and gestures, pen detection) is working as I'd expect.

Please open an issue with the linux-surface project at GitHub. They would be able to provide a better solution than the volunteers on this site.
